# Не меняется текст UILabel

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

У меня есть некоторый **UILabel titleLabel**, который инициализируется в конструкторе, Frame же указывается в LayoutSubview.

По задумке, при нажатии кнопки (вызывается метод *btnOKClicked*) должен меняться текст того самого **titleLabel**:

> ```
>     public void btnOKClicked()
>     {
>         titleLabel.Text = "Changed";
>
>         Thread.Sleep(1000);
> ```

Однако ничего не происходит.

Вопрос:чего я не понимаю?

Comment: Зачем 
        `Thread.Sleep(1000);`?

Comment: На самом деле после указанных строк осуществляется другой код, поэтому, чтобы убедиться в том, что он не влияет, поставил Thread.Sleep(1000);

Comment: К этому и задал вопрос. UI операции исполняются на главном потоке и поэтому из-за Thread.Sleep изменения стали бы видны только после указанного интервала времени.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что **Thread.Sleep(x)** заблокировал основной поток

Заменил его    **await Task.Delay(x)**